# Как убрать дубли предложений в intellisense vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Мне не нравиться что intellisense предлагает по два варианта, один для нового импорта, другой для обновления уже существующего. Какой смысл предлагать отдельный импорт из той же библиотеки, приходиться тратить время на выбор, потому что если выбирать на шару, линтер будет ругаться на дубли импортов. Можно ли как-то отключить варианты с новым импортом если уже есть импорт?

[image: Дубли предложений в intellisense]

Comment: Мм.. Тема monokai? А не понравится Monokai Meage в расширениях vscode?

Comment: Пробовал, там цвета более вялые. А в этой теме пёстрые и весёлые.